# Time efficient way to implement Multi-Armed-Bandits?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, performance, reinforcement-learning

I'm doing a research on Multi-Armed Bandit (MAB) problem with approx. 1 million arms. In contrast, the number of iterations is of course much larger, about 10-20 million.

Most MAB-algorithms require an argmax operator (argmax of the action space) that has to be executed in each iteration in order to select the current arm (which maximizes a given selection criterion). Regardless of the chosen programming language for implementation, this procedure/ this argmax operator over the entire action space (1 million arms) is very time-consuming.

Does anyone have some ideas on how to implement MAB algorithms in a time-efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

Store the values in a priority queue.  Typically, in each iteration you will update the value for only a single arm, so you need to change the key of a single value in the priority queue, which can be done in $O(\log n)$ time, where $n$ is the number of arms.  You can also find the argmax in $O(\log n)$ time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps doing a 0-order search which requires you to evaluate every choice? If you have the ability to parameterize the selection criteria analytically you could find the maxima faster using [1st or even 2nd-order methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201384/what-is-the-definition-of-a-first-order-method).

Also, along the lines of what D.W said, but even faster, if you use a [max-heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_heap) as an implementation for the priority queue, you can actually get the **max** value in $O(1)$ (updating the "value" of each arm, would be $O(\lg N)$).